# How to set height for header and footer for UITableView in xib file for ios 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am trying to set section height using only a xib file for my grouped `UITableView`.
There are fields in xib file where height for footer and header can be set:

[image]

I don't implement methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

And it works on ios 6 but on ios 7 sizes of header and footer are not related with xib file.

Comment: not related with xib file means be clear what happen in ios7

Comment: There is a fixed size not depended on xib file.

Comment: possible post your screen shot for both iOS version